# Why am I getting a syntax error comparing 2 timestamps in my SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-delete

What is the correct way to compare a (timestamp + time_elapsed) > date?

```
DO 
$$
DECLARE test_date timestamp:='2023-04-10';
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO base_building 
             SELECT constructionqueue.building_id, 
                    constructionqueue.base_id
             FROM buildingcost, constructionqueue
             WHERE buildingcost.building_id=constructionqueue.building_id 
             AND (start_date+build_time) >' || test_date;
   
    EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM constructionq C 
             USING buildingcost B 
             WHERE B.building_id = C.building_id 
             AND (C.start_date + B.build_time) >' || test_date;

END
$$;
```

**Gives the following error:**

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "00"
LINE 3: ...building_id AND (start_date+build_time) >2023-04-10 00:00:00
^
QUERY:
INSERT INTO base_building SELECT constructionqueue.building_id, constructionqueue.base_id
FROM buildingcost, constructionqueue
WHERE buildingcost.building_id=constructionqueue.building_id AND (start_date+build_time) >2023-04-10 00:00:00
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at EXECUTE

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Which database system do you use?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: ...why are you using Dynamic SQL for this instead of a normal parameterized query?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: As @Dai already has commented, use parameters instead. `>2023-04-10 00:00:00` starts fine with 2023 minus 04 minus 10, but suddenly finds `00`, which isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Wrap the date in quotes: `... >''' || test_date || ''''`

Comment: Apologies for the lack of context. I am using psql (14.1, server 15.2). I have tried declaring test_date as a date and casting the other variables. Date(start_date+build_time) >' || test_date. I get the following error:  ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone > integer
LINE 2: ...tionqueue.building_id AND (start_date+build_time) >2023-04-1...